# I recovered a file from chrome://cache, how do I read it?

Tags: file, google-chrome

This is the data it displays:

```
http://krill.larvit.se/resihop_dev/style.css
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 17 Jul 2012 20:36:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Last-Modified: Mon, 16 Jul 2012 23:33:42 GMT
ETag: "3003d8-92f-4c4fadc326180"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 871
Content-Type: text/css
00000000:  4a  01  00  00  03  08  00  00  68  fc  1b  c8  a2  23  2e  00  J.......h....#..
00000010:  c4  c4  1c  c8  a2  23  2e  00  0f  01  00  00  48  54  54  50  .....#......HTTP
00000020:  2f  31  2e  31  20  32  30  30  20  4f  4b  00  44  61  74  65  /1.1 200 OK.Date
00000030:  3a  20  54  75  65  2c  20  31  37  20  4a  75  6c  20  32  30  : Tue, 17 Jul 20
00000040:  31  32  20  32  30  3a  33  36  3a  31  37  20  47  4d  54  00  12 20:36:17 GMT.
00000050:  53  65  72  76  65  72  3a  20  41  70  61  63  68  65  2f  32  Server: Apache/2
00000060:  2e  32  2e  31  36  20  28  44  65  62  69  61  6e  29  00  4c  .2.16 (Debian).L
00000070:  61  73  74  2d  4d  6f  64  69  66  69  65  64  3a  20  4d  6f  ast-Modified: Mo
00000080:  6e  2c  20  31  36  20  4a  75  6c  20  32  30  31  32  20  32  n, 16 Jul 2012 2
00000090:  33  3a  33  33  3a  34  32  20  47  4d  54  00  45  54  61  67  3:33:42 GMT.ETag
000000a0:  3a  20  22  33  30  30  33  64  38  2d  39  32  66  2d  34  63  : "3003d8-92f-4c
000000b0:  34  66  61  64  63  33  32  36  31  38  30  22  00  41  63  63  4fadc326180".Acc
000000c0:  65  70  74  2d  52  61  6e  67  65  73  3a  20  62  79  74  65  ept-Ranges: byte
000000d0:  73  00  56  61  72  79  3a  20  41  63  63  65  70  74  2d  45  s.Vary: Accept-E
000000e0:  6e  63  6f  64  69  6e  67  00  43  6f  6e  74  65  6e  74  2d  ncoding.Content-
000000f0:  45  6e  63  6f  64  69  6e  67  3a  20  67  7a  69  70  00  43  Encoding: gzip.C
00000100:  6f  6e  74  65  6e  74  2d  4c  65  6e  67  74  68  3a  20  38  ontent-Length: 8
00000110:  37  31  00  43  6f  6e  74  65  6e  74  2d  54  79  70  65  3a  71.Content-Type:
00000120:  20  74  65  78  74  2f  63  73  73  00  00  00  1c  75  7f  de   text/css....u..
00000130:  67  1f  5e  3e  ea  80  b1  88  00  f0  37  0c  0b  00  00  00  g.^>......7.....
00000140:  33  31  2e  32  34  2e  36  37  2e  36  37  00  50  00          31.24.67.67.P.
00000000:  1f  8b  08  00  00  00  00  00  00  03  8d  55  db  4e  e3  30  ...........U.N.0
00000010:  10  7d  6e  be  c2  6a  b5  62  41  04  28  2d  2c  4d  df  10  .}n..j.bA.(-,M..
00000020:  ec  6f  ac  a6  89  93  78  71  ec  c8  76  81  6e  c5  77  ed  .o....xq..v.n.w.
00000030:  fb  7e  d9  8e  6f  49  1a  0a  42  55  a5  d8  99  cb  99  33  .~..oI..BU.....3
00000040:  67  26  97  67  1b  d0  2c  27  1c  76  72  6b  ce  2e  93  59  g&.g..,'.vrk...Y
00000050:  2e  85  01  26  a8  da  27  93  17  56  98  3a  23  f3  ab  ab  ...&..'..V.:#...
00000060:  6f  eb  64  d2  4a  cd  0c  93  22  23  b0  d1  92  6f  0d  c5  o.d.J..."#...o..
00000070:  cb  9a  b2  aa  36  9d  8d  7c  a6  aa  e4  f2  25  23  35  2b  ....6..|....%#5+
00000080:  0a  2a  d6  c9  5b  92  cc  38  2d  0d  f9  5a  3c  6b  9a  91  .*..[..8-..Z<k..
00000090:  2b  7c  ba  3c  c3  10  4c  54  c4  d4  94  6c  2b  be  23  da  +|.<..LT...l+.#.
000000a0:  6c  cb  92  80  71  37  1b  69  8c  6c  88  2c  dd  a9  81  16  l...q7.i.l.,....
000000b0:  c1  f7  68  ae  5d  06  6f  93  91  d4  1d  3b  24  2d  42  69  ..h.].o....;$-Bi
000000c0:  40  55  4c  b8  4c  f6  1e  fd  7f  e5  20  9e  41  5b  9c  2d  @UL.L..... .A[.-
000000d0:  14  36  b3  c7  31  aa  f0  a0  06  e7  ab  ec  fb  de  2b  55  .6..1.........+U
000000e0:  d1  be  7d  45  fb  82  e9  16  d9  cd  c8  86  cb  fc  c9  82  ..}E............
000000f0:  82  fc  a9  52  72  2b  8a  34  97  5c  aa  8c  bc  d4  ec  73  ...Rr+.4.\.....s
00000100:  2e  75  ae  24  e7  7d  f2  e5  62  e1  62  1f  65  30  a4  f7  .u.$.}..b.b.e0..
00000110:  d9  8d  6c  63  8d  97  67  0f  54  b3  4a  20  4f  0d  15  db  ..lc..g.T.J O...
00000120:  fd  07  ee  91  33  ef  ef  83  4d  42  2d  1d  2f  f6  ec  c8  ....3...MB-./...
00000130:  19  d0  38  28  ac  2f  e9  10  30  a2  b0  a9  09  67  98  9d  ..8(./..0....g..
00000140:  33  6d  52  6d  76  9c  a6  66  d7  d2  8c  08  29  e8  80  30  3mRmv..f....)..0
00000150:  26  38  b3  17  6f  d1  27  db  d0  52  2a  6a  1b  64  45  4a  &8..o.'..R*j.dEJ
00000160:  05  56  39  fd  f7  97  4c  87  81  b3  92  29  8c  9b  d7  8c  .V9...L....)....
00000170:  17  47  1d  bc  f5  46  16  3b  7b  5f  e2  7d  5a  42  c3  38  .G...F.;{_.}ZB.8
00000180:  76  68  ca  b7  39  2b  80  54  0a  44  41  a7  e7  06  6a  d9  vh..9+.T.DA...j.
00000190:  c0  39  b6  a1  00  01  e7  a0  18  f0  73  0d  42  a7  9a  2a  .9........s.B..*
000001a0:  56  ae  83  bb  66  7f  10  fd  dc  b7  c4  62  4e  bb  46  fe  V...f......bN.F.
000001b0:  70  77  87  5a  03  07  c7  36  7e  32  5b  dc  df  ac  56  77  pw.Z...6~2[...Vw
000001c0:  b6  4f  f4  d5  a4  05  cd  a5  02  df  11  4f  06  9a  27  90  .O.........O..'.
000001d0:  d5  56  09  fb  23  46  48  35  55  91  a5  f7  42  f4  b3  34  .V..#FH5U...B..4
000001e0:  bf  09  d4  fb  f7  a4  9e  ef  0f  80  33  51  63  35  66  1d  ..........3Qc5f.
000001f0:  51  d9  f2  77  4e  08  0a  a3  a7  51  0f  73  ec  38  8a  84  Q..wN....Q.s.8..
00000200:  15  64  f6  b8  b2  bf  58  fe  4b  28  56  48  d5  00  1f  aa  .d....X.K(VH....
00000210:  e4  ce  8a  84  74  04  a4  03  31  a2  1a  b9  04  8c  8f  6a  ....t...1......j
00000220:  bc  f0  4f  07  92  c0  da  14  ff  7e  02  bf  e1  35  f5  af  ..O......~...5..
00000230:  2f  2a  56  9e  9c  3a  e7  e0  e0  65  14  8b  8d  38  63  b5  /*V..:...e...8c.
00000240:  bd  11  81  03  ad  2b  ca  91  be  67  1a  a7  23  5d  06  0f  .....+...g..#]..
00000250:  c4  84  56  26  b5  28  2c  2c  7b  d0  e3  6d  70  d8  cb  24  ..V&.(,,{..mp..$
00000260:  58  8d  15  dd  89  f9  0b  24  1e  45  d6  4f  1a  6d  42  ae  X......$.E.O.mB.
00000270:  90  89  35  55  b7  be  46  ab  06  97  05  e0  c9  b6  dd  7b  ..5U..F........{
00000280:  58  c1  0c  f7  79  f0  f2  ba  b8  f5  4e  61  42  17  37  73  X...y.....NaB.7s
00000290:  7b  7c  ef  e6  d9  1b  91  ec  b5  9e  73  0a  a8  17  07  e2  {|........s.....
000002a0:  48  c2  c1  9e  0d  ad  8f  ad  11  d0  d0  fd  48  3e  1b  c9  H...........H>..
000002b0:  0b  ff  b6  a1  5a  43  45  7b  e7  77  ad  35  ac  a1  a4  9f  ....ZCE{.w.5....
000002c0:  23  32  bb  7d  b8  5b  de  2f  3f  9d  a3  e0  f4  d5  61  72  #2.}.[./?.....ar
000002d0:  e6  83  0c  ab  55  27  f8  30  ef  f3  c1  6c  77  10  e3  aa  ....U'.0...lw...
000002e0:  cd  65  83  0b  c9  68  ab  a3  f8  fc  91  94  6e  dc  98  5c  .e...h......n..\
000002f0:  8d  76  68  fc  38  cc  1e  1f  1e  7f  fe  5c  1e  4b  6e  61  .vh.8......\.Kna
00000300:  c6  e0  5e  81  0d  42  89  cb  67  e1  74  fd  b1  02  e3  8a  ..^..B..g.t.....
00000310:  ee  30  a1  bd  c3  12  fe  eb  c9  58  ed  7d  b2  d1  17  b4  .0.......X.}....
00000320:  ff  c8  f5  4b  bb  37  b6  8d  7a  67  f0  51  f3  07  f5  5c  ...K.7..zg.Q...\
00000330:  d0  d7  16  17  f1  a8  ac  f1  97  c6  a2  cd  d1  03  f5  66  ...............f
00000340:  57  46  f0  bf  68  45  75  8a  cd  4f  15  6d  29  98  f5  78  WF..hEu..O.m)..x
00000350:  29  5e  5f  7b  02  8f  e4  73  78  8f  6e  b6  b7  e4  3f  49  )^_{...sx.n...?I
00000360:  7b  1f  b2  2f  09  00  00                                      {../...
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133490/how-can-i-read-chrome-cache-files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read Chrome Cache files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133490/how-can-i-read-chrome-cache-files)