# Decode gzip Chrome Cache

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gzip, browser-cache

I messed up this morning and deleted half of an important .css file.

Luckily I found a cached version in my Chrome folder.
The file is unreadable though.

```
0000fc40: d2 19 68 03 5a 2b 96 39 94 02 ce 31 c3 eb 2f 18  ..h.Z+.9...1../.
```

Is there any way to decode it to plain text and get the CSS back?
I tried converters, searched for an answer via Google but every answer that was found was not working out.

I thought that the 2nd column is hexadecimal. I tried decoding it, but the result was `ÒhZ+9Î1Ãë/`. Not something I can work with.

Could you help me out?

Full version of the file: https://jpst.it/UYPk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read Chrome Cache files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133490/how-can-i-read-chrome-cache-files)

Answer (score 2):

Took solution from there
http://www.insentricity.com/a.cl/241/how-to-recover-data-from-chromes-cache

```
xxd -r < cached-hex.txt | gunzip > cached.html
where cached-hex.txt -- binary of file body
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Found the cached version of the HTML file in my chrome:cache which was created when I edited the CSS and saved it. It contained the plain text of my css in hexadecimal